# illegal characters in path error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am trying to launch an excel file but get an error, Am I missing something?

I try to launch an excel file but get:

> illegal characters in path

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult ExportData(DateTime Date)
    {

        return File("~\\Reports\\ExcelExport.xlsm?Date=" + Date, "application/vnd.ms-excel" , Server.UrlEncode("~\\Reports\\ExcelExport.xlsm?Date=" + Date));

    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function ExportToExcel() {

    var link = '/Report/ExportData';
    var Date= $("#Date").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { Date: Date},
        success: function (result) {                
        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
    });

};
```

Comment: Where is that error occurring, the browser or server log? I would check the format of the Date variable because it may contain colons or other characters which don't translate well to the Windows filesystem

Comment: @providencemac Its returned to my javaScript function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in a hybrid URL/physical file path.  Try something like this to get the physical file path if it's on disk:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Reports/ExcelExport.xlsm"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You're including the string value of the DateTime parameter in your path. That will look something like this: 10/4/2013 5:00:17 PM. Both **/** and **:** are invalid characters in a Windows path.

Answer (score 2):

Question marks are not valid characters for filenames.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx